# how to repeat a loop in C

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to create a program that display the value of days in a week.
Monday is 1, Tuesday is 2, Wednesday is 3, ... Sunday is 7.
If the user input is 3 then the output will be 1 2 3.
If the user input is 10, then the output will be 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 1 2 3.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for( int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        if(i > 7)
        {
            continue;
        }
        printf("%d ", i);
    }
 
    return 0;
}
```

If I input 10, this code will only output 1 2 3 4 5 6 7.

Comment: " If the user input is 1 then the output will be 1 2 3." Your loop won't even do that. Why should the input `1` lead to the output `1 2 3`? What's the algorithm for that?

Comment: As for the problem of "repeating", what do you know about the *modulo operator `%`*? I suggest you do some research about it.

Comment: Start by creating output 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10. Then modify the print to use `%` operator on the value it prints.

Comment: modulo is the remainder if we divide 2 integers

Comment: Okay, so what is the remainder of e.g. `6 % 7`? What about `7 % 7`? Or `8 % 7` and `9 % 7`? Do you start to see a pattern emerging?

Comment: I'm so sorry I made a mistake when I type the problem, I mean if the user input is 3, then the output will be 1 2 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
`#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n;
    int p=1;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for( int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        if(p == 8)
        {
            p = 1;
        }
        printf("%d ", p);
        
        p = p+1;
        
    }
 
    return 0;
}`
```

Answer (score 2):

Just write

```
for( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
{
    printf( "%d ", i % 7 + 1 );
}
putchar( '\n' );
```

Or it is better to introduce a named constant for the magic number 7 as for example

```
enum { DAYS_IN_WEEK = 7 };

for( int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    printf("%d ", i % DAYS_IN_WEEK + 1 );
}
putchar( '\n' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use modulo operator or general counter:

```
void printDays(unsigned day)
{
    while(day)
    {
        for(unsigned wd = 1; day && wd < 8; wd++, day--)
            printf("%u ", wd);
    }
    printf("\n");
}


void printDays1(unsigned day)
{
    for(unsigned d = 0; d < day; d++) printf("%u ", d % 7 + 1);
    printf("\n");
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/6W6Gz7G9o